# Understanding python import of gevent

Tags: python, gevent, monkeypatching

This fails for me:

```
import gevent
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
```

This works:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

Is there anything wrong I am trying to do by accessing gevent.monkey

Also, I am confused on this snippet:

```
import gevent as ge
from gevent import monkey
ge.monkey.patch_all()
```

what makes ge.monkey accessible now? if I comment from gevent import monkey, this doesn't work. I have used

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

which works perfectly fine but monkey doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`monkey` is a *module* inside the `gevent` module.

`datetime` is a *class* inside the `datetime` module.

When you `import x`, all of `x`'s objects are imported (in the `x` namespace). *But child modules are not imported*

While your top and bottom examples look identical, the type of object makes all the difference.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot. Could you please explain my third snippet too. How come ge.monkey is accessible in this case. Will all future imports of the module gevent be binded to ge automatically

Comment: Yes, exactly. `ge` is a local reference to the `gevent` module. By importing `monkey` from `gevent`, the local `ge` object, being just a pointer, gets the same access to `monkey`